# Javascript nested .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I try to create a calculator keypad. 
Onclick functions work properly. My problem is with .each() funtion. How can I traverse the my `buttonArray` ?. I could not handle the nested arrays and appends `<p>` to `<div>` as same `<input>` append to `<p>`.

My script is like:

```js
var buttonArray = [
  [{
      type: 'button',
      className: 'sil',
      value: 'C'
    }, {
      type: 'button',
      className: 'hepsiniSil',
      value: 'AC'
    },

  ],
  [{
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '7'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '8'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '9'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '*'
  }],
  [{
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '4'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '5'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '6'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '-'
  }],
  [{
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '1'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '2'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '3'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '+'
  }],
  [{
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '0'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'esit',
    value: '=',
    click: 'esittir'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '/'
  }]
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(function(index, buttonArray) {
    $("<p>").each(function(subIndex, subArrays) {
      $("<input>")
        .addClass(subArrays.className)
        .val(subArrays.val)
        .appendTo(this)
    });
  });
});
```

and I want to this output:

```html
<p>
  <input type="button" class="sil" value="C" style="width:50px">
  <input type="button" class="hepsiniSil" value="AC" style="width:50px">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="7">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="8">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="9">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="*">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="4">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="5">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="6">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="-">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="1">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="2">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="3">
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="+">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="0">
  <input type="button" class="esit" value="=" style="width:50px" onclick='esittir()'>
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="/">

</p>
```

Comment: Is there any error? Can you check the console?

Comment: There is no error. But I am sure, `.each()` function should not be like this. @RaxWeber

Comment: Your `each` loop not taking the `buttonArray ` to loop. Change it like this; `$.each(buttonArray ,function(index, value)` And you should change the other codes according to this.

Comment: @A.OzanEkici In this situation what will be value ?

Comment: It will be your first element in the array. Just check the @OriDrori 's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) 1st parameter is the array to iterate, the 2nd is the callback:

> jQuery.each( array, callback )

The callback returns the iterated item as the 2nd param:

> callback
>
> Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value ) The
>   function that will be executed on every object.

In addition `this` in `$.each()` is the value of the item, you can't append to it.

You need to iterate the outer array, create a `<p>` element an append him to the container. Then iterate the sub arrays, create `<input>` (or just a `<button>` element), and append them to their `<p>` container:

```js
var buttonArray = [
  [{
      type: 'button',
      className: 'sil',
      value: 'C'
    }, {
      type: 'button',
      className: 'hepsiniSil',
      value: 'AC'
    },

  ],
  [{
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '7'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '8'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '9'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '*'
  }],
  [{
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '4'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '5'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '6'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '-'
  }],
  [{
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '1'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '2'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '3'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '+'
  }],
  [{
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '0'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'esit',
    value: '=',
    click: 'esittir'
  }, {
    type: 'button',
    className: 'buttons',
    value: '/'
  }]

];


var $calculator = $('#calculator');

$.each(buttonArray, function(index, buttons) {
  var $p = $('<p>').appendTo($calculator);

  $.each(buttons, function(subIndex, button) {
    $('<input>')
      .addClass(button.className)
      .prop('type', button.type)
      .val(button.value)
      .appendTo($p)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="calculator"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked. One more question how can I handle the width ?. Some of buttons have width property.

Comment: similar to the handling of `className`, just set up a property before hand, and the process it: `.width(button.myWidth)`

Comment: You're welcome :) You can a add a relevant class with the width to each button, or add a width property to the array, and set it to each button using `.width(button.width)`.